# How to replace hyphen-minus with minus?

Tags: javascript, cypress, parsefloat

In my test, I need to `parseFloat()` a string. The issue is that hyphen-minus instantly occurs `NaN`. Visual Studio Code cannot distinguish hyphen minus from minus so that I am not able to replace on a string. Is there any workaround for this? My code:

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
  "parseNumber",
  (locator, responseValue) => {
    let parsedText;
    locator()
      .invoke("text")
      .then((text) => {
        parsedText = parseFloat(text.replace("-", "-").replace(" ", "").replace(",", "."));
        expect(parsedText).to.eq(responseValue);
      });
  }
);
```

Comment: The minus and hyphen sign are the same thing in JavaScript.

Comment: May I know what kind of value you're trying to parse?

Comment: I have to parse many different values. E.g. -34,32%

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it in that way:

```
parsedText = parseFloat(
          text
            .replace(/−/, "-")
            .replace(" ", "")
            .replace(/,/, ".")
            .replace(/%/, "")
        );
```

Resolved, thank you for the answers.